# parse ckeditor content and apply tags instead of displaying them on the screen

Tags: html, ckeditor

I have a problem parsing the content of CKEditor. I have saved the data into mongoDB but when I retrieve the content to display, it shows the tags instead of parsing them.

The **content had thi**s formatting *when I saved it. This is how* I want it to display ***when I retrieve it from the database***.

But this is the content I am getting when I retrieve from the database. I want it to apply the tags but not displaying them. so I can have the same formatting as I entered.

```
<p>The <strong>content had thi</strong>s formatting <em>when I saved it. This is how</em> I want it to display <strong><em>when I retrieve it from the database</em></strong>.</p>
```

My html page is the following when I tried to display the content:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">


    <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.8.0/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>

</head>

<body>    
    <div id="pgContent">
        <div class="container">
            <span class="line"></span>
            <div id="msgContent" style="max-width:800px; font-size:16px;">&lt;p&gt;The &lt;strong&gt;content had thi&lt;/strong&gt;s formatting &lt;em&gt;when I saved it. This is how&lt;/em&gt; I want it to display &lt;strong&gt;&lt;em&gt;when I retrieve it from the database&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/strong&gt;.&lt;/p&gt;</div></div></div>

</body>
```

There is not jquery/javascript added to it. I added javascript but it is transforming the div into an editor again:

```
         CKEDITOR.replace('msgContent',
{
    entities: false,
    basicEntities: false,
    entities_greek: false,
    entities_latin: false,
    htmlDecodeOutput:true,
}
```

I used the following when writing the message:'

```
         CKEDITOR.replace('msgEditor')
```

**Update :** 
The data in the database (mongoDB) is shown as follow:

```
<p>The <strong>content had thi</strong>s formatting <em>when I saved it. This is how</em> I want it to display <strong><em>when I retrieve it from the database</em></strong>.</p>\r\n
```

Thank you for now

Comment: Check if data in database is also html encoded. Also, there is no htmlDecodeOutput configuration option.

Comment: HI Wizard, I removed htmlDecodeOutput option but is still the same problem. Do you have any (other) idea of how I could get my text displayed and formatted properly? Thank you

Comment: Now that you checked that data in database is fine, what is the command you use to output the data? Are you perhaps using PHP and `htmlspecialchars` or `htmlentities`?

Comment: When I fetched the data, I just sent it to the view engine (handlebars). I did not do anything special. I am working with NodeJS, Handlebars, and MongoDB. The following is the promise that renders the data.

Comment: Can you post the part of the Handlebars template that affects `msgContent`?

Comment: **update** When I fetched the data, I just sent it to the view engine (handlebars). I did not do anything special. I am working with NodeJS, Handlebars, and MongoDB. The following is the promise that renders the data. `.then(message => {
      res.render('message/displayMsg', {
        message: message
      })
    }) ` I am not using PHP in this project. I would like to work on JavaScript only. Because the data the data was saved using CKEditor and so it has HTML tags, do we have to add something from CKEditor again while trying to display the content?. Thanks

Comment: Ok. Give a second. Thanks

Comment: ` `   <div class="msg-content-box">
      <div class="container">
        <span class="line"></span>
        <div id="msgContent" style="max-width:800px; font-size:16px;">{{message.content}}</div>

      </div>
    </div>`` I don't have any Handlebars helper for formatting the data. Do I need one? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) docs:

> Handlebars HTML-escapes values returned by a {{expression}}. If you
>   don't want Handlebars to escape a value, use the "triple-stash", {{{.

So, in your template change `{{message.content}}` to `{{{message.content}}}`

Comment: it worked. fantastic. you saved my journey. Thank you very much.

Comment: Great! If you would like, please mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: I did. Thanks again.